# How can I load a Local html file (not in my classpath) to WebView?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine, javafx-webview

I'm learning javafx and am creating a TodoList application. I want to include certain features like text styling, using bullet lists etc. and for that I have added an HTMLEditor to my app, which stores html files for my WebView to load. To test the saving and loading of the html files I have saved a sample 'test.html' file (which is not in my classpath) and want the WebView to load it.
here's some of my code:

**Main.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>
<GridPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="sample.Controller" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <WebView GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" fx:id="webView"/>
</GridPane>
```

**Fxml Controller.java**

```
public class Controller{

@FXML private WebView webView;
private WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

 @FXML
    public void initialize() throws IOException{
        //code for some ArrayList initialization

        engine.load("/home/jyotiproy/TodoOutput/test.html");

    }
}
```

**Main.java that loads the program**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Todo List");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1200, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I'm getting no errors or exceptions. There is no typo in the path of the 'test.html' and the html editor works fine and saves the test.html, but the WebView loads nothing.
Here is my app structure:
[image: WebView]
[image: HTMLEditor]

Comment: Read as a `File`. Convert the file content to a `String`.

Comment: `String htmlString = new String (Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));`

Comment: @Sedrick used the following: `` File f = new File("/home/jyotiproy/TodoOutput/test.html");
        engine.load(f.toString());`` still nothing

Comment: That's not how to convert a file's content to a string.

Comment: Did you try `System.out.println(f.toString())` to see what the problem is?

Comment: the output is the file path: /home/....../test.html

Comment: Which is what it should be. Use my second comment.

Comment: @Sedrick Pardon me if I get it wrong, but the code from the second comment converts the entire file contents to a string and then by the .load method, we pass that string to the WebEngine? I did that, but nothing happens :(

Comment: The [`WebEngine#load(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#load(java.lang.String)) methods expects a URL in the form of a `String`. Try something like `"file:///home/jyotiproy/TodoOutput/test.html"`.  If you use the approach suggested by @Sedrick (i.e. read the _contents_ of the file into a `String`) then you'll want to use [`WebEngine#loadContent(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @Slaw I used this ```engine.load("file:///home/jyotiproy/TodoOutput/test.html");``` but still nothing happens. Now I'm thinking whether I have done something wrong in the FXML declaration or have  not associated it with the controller properly. Is there something wrong with that code?

Comment: @Slaw good catch on the `loadContent(String)`.

Comment: Well, `private WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();` looks like it should be throwing an NPE. If it's not, then you're doing something that isn't being shown (i.e. your code is not a [mre]).

Comment: @Slaw used the .loadContent this way ```File f = new File("/home/jyotiproy/TodoOutput/test.html");```
        ```String htmlString = new String (Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(f.toString())));```
       ``` engine.loadContent(htmlString);```  still nothing happens

Comment: @Slaw I've added the complete code (which concerns the WebView) please check it.

Comment: Never instantiate fields that are meant to be injected by an `FXMLLoader`. The `WebEngine` you have a reference to is associated with the `WebView` you created, not the `WebView` that was created (and injected) by the `FXMLLoader` (i.e. the one being displayed).

Comment: @Slaw Thank you very much. I rewrote the code and this time did not instantiate the WebView but only the WebEngine and now it work as it should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Slaw and @Sidrick the question was solved.
The changes that were needed in the original code were the addition of the `file://` in the `engine.load()` part of the code.

**Working Code**

```
@FXML private WebView webView;



    @FXML
    public void initialize() throws IOException{
        //Some ArrayList Initialization 

        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.load("file:///home/jyotiproy/Todolist/test2.html");
    }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Working app]

Comment: it's not forum but a knowledge base produced by the community :) Personally, I agree with explaining a downvote (wasn't mine but could have been because you didn't do your very best - provide a [mcve] - to make the question answerable, piling up comments is not the way to go, so your code indeed is far from _adequate_).  But it's explitely _not_ mandatory (please read the help pages on voting). And with all due respect: judging by your reputation, a statement like _doesn't fullfill the purpose of this site_ is quite daring ;)

Comment: it's not complete - I can't throw the files into my IDE, compile and run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Almost. One of the problems you've described is that the code runs without errors but fails to produce the desired results. The reason was evident in the images of your code that you added (and then [correctly removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)). However, the code you're currently showing (assuming normal execution) will result in a `NullPointerException` because you don't show the erroneous initialization of the `webView` field. It'd also be nice to have the bare-bones `Application` class.

Comment: Note I also was not the downvoter, but just to add: Keep in mind a [mre] is just that—an example of the problem. One of the things I often see with newer users is a tendency to code dump their entire project (not minimal) or simply omit at least half the code which they _believe_ is not relevant (not complete). The example should be _specially created_ for Stack Overflow and contain the _minimal_ amount of code to _reproduce_ the problem. The [mre] link provides some useful tips on how to isolate the problem, which while in the process of doing one might even solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @Slaw thank you for clarifying. The code I didn't provide was that of the Main class which creates the stage to show the webView and launches the program. It may be sufficient now.

Comment: looks good now :) As a very last nit-pick: _minimal_ shouldn't contain anything that's unrelated .. such as code comments about irrelevant ommitted lines, but that's certainly not important <g>

Comment: @kleopatra got it. Next time I'll keep such things in mind! Thanks! :)